# Supermicro X8DTT-F Ram Compatibility

Tags: memory, motherboard, compatibility, supermicro

can anyone help me if this ram specs is compatible with
Supermicro X8DTT-F?

Manufacturer    Hynix
Manufacturer Part # 
HMT151R7BFR4C-G7
Memory Type DDR3 SDRAM
Capacity    4GB
Pins    240 Pin
Bus Type    PC-8500
Error Correction    Registered ECC
Cycle Time  1.875ns
Cas CL7
Data Transfer Rate  1066Mhz
Memory Clock    133Mhz
Rank    Rank 2
Voltage 1.5

---

I bought this ram for X8SIU-F but to my surprise it is not compatible with it as it does not support 4GB Memory Devices. If I buy a Supermicro
X8DTT-F Do you Think it will be compatible? Thank you so much! I tried looking at the supermicro website for the motherboard specifications but
I might make a mistake again on reading if its compatible. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SuperMicro X8DTT-F Motherboard supports 192 GB Registered ECC memory and 48 GB if ECC Memory is used.

The part # HMT151R7BFR4C-G7 is compatible.

Manufacturer Specs:
http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/QPI/5500/X8DTT-F.cfm

Refer this:

http://www.memorystock.com/memory/SuperMicroX8DTTF.html

Answer (score 0):

In selecting RAM, make sure the manufacturer is supported under the supported brands, ensure your memory capacity is not greater than one port can handle, and that your timing is compatible with the motherboard.  The manufacturer part should be easy.  The capacity is 4GB like you listed. The timing is 1066MHZ. Make sure this is a number listed.